# How to create local variable that throws exception? Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a new object in my main class, however, the class the object is referencing throws alot of IOExceptions.  I know this is simple, but I just can't figure out the syntax to create this local variable.  Please help

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

     ProcessBuilderExample start2 = new ProcessBuilderExample();
```

Dr Java is giving me the error "Object must be caught or thrown"

I tried this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

         ProcessBuilderExample start2 = new ProcessBuilderExample() throws IOException;
```

I get an error from this too.  How do I declare this?

Comment: Please quote the error message accurately. It doesn't say that, unless `Variable` is the name of a class that extends `Exception`, in which case it is a truly terrible name.

Comment: It doesn't say '`Object` must be caught or thrown' either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either `catch` it with a `try` block, or modify your method signature to allow it through. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    ProcessBuilderExample start2 = new ProcessBuilderExample();
    // ...
```

**or**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try { 
        ProcessBuilderExample start2 = new ProcessBuilderExample();
        // ...
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for thanks!